# R: Why does strptime always return NA when I try to format a character-date string?

Tags: r, date

I am trying to change a character to date-string using strptime. The data, however, always returns NA.

```
date_time_info
1 16mar2012 11:23 PM
2 04feb2000  8:41 AM
3 25dec2022  5:55 PM
```

I read in this data and called it dora.
I then run the following to create a new variable called "date_time_info2" as a date-string:

```
dora$date_time_info2<-strptime(dora$date_time_info,"%d%b%Y %I%M %p")
```

When I display dora again:

```
  date_time_info date_time_info2
1 16mar2012 11:23 PM            <NA>
2 04feb2000  8:41 AM            <NA>
3 25dec2022  5:55 PM            <NA>
```

Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: One issue with your code is that it is missing a colon , i.e. try with `%I:%M` instead of `%I%M`.

Comment: This got it to populate! Thank you. However, it is still not quite the format I am looking for, how do I cut seconds and have it print AM/PM times?:  date_time_info     date_time_info2
1   1 16mar2012 11:23 PM 2012-03-16 23:23:00
2   1 04feb2000  8:41 AM 2000-02-04 08:41:00
3   0 25dec2022  5:55 PM 2022-12-25 17:55:00

Comment: The question is what you want to achieve. `strptime` converts from a character to a proper datetime class which includes the seconds. If you don't want seconds and have PM/AM then you could format your datetime using e.g. `format(dora$date_time_info2, "%d%b%Y %I:%M %p")`. But this means you are converting to a character and in some sense your are right back where you started.